# i want to display an echo before the query execute in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display "preparing data..." before the query execute.
ex:

```
echo "preparing data...";

$var = $link->query("insert into table select * from db.table");

if($var === true){
  echo " preparing data complete ";
}else{
  echo " some error ";
}
```

my query complete after 30mins or more , cause database table contains thousands of data.
instead of "preparing data..." will be display on the browser before the query execute or finished executing. it will display at the same time as "preparing data complete".

Comment: your browser will not render anything to the screen, until your whole script finishes. you will need to separate the database call, into a separate script, and call it via ajax or something simmilar, if you want to show output to the browser, and execute the query in the background.

Comment: so i'll separate my query on other .php then use ajax to call that .php on main.php?

Comment: yes, but even so, if your script takes too long, without the correct timeout settings, most likely the browser will timeout the underlying connection, and you will get no result. why would you need to perform such a resource consuming operation in the browser? I mean, what is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ive done resolving the problem on timeout. sorry im not that good in english , but due to pandemic , accessing database via browser is what i want to achieve, rather than installing an multiple different desktop app to all the computer in a company that needed to access the database. this is only for intra-company

Comment: You might be interested in [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events)

Comment: i check ajax and try to use it , and it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser if it works or not. But sometimes this works:

At the start of the file add:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
  ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
  ob_end_clean();
  set_time_limit(0);
```

and after every `echo` command add `flush()`:

```
<?php
  echo "This is a test";
  flush();
  // Do some things
  echo "Test 2";
  flush();
?>
```

Comment: ohhh i try ajax and it works but i will also try this , thanks